# C# HttpClient PostAsync blocks forever

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have a strange behavior that I can't manage to explain.
In an async function, an awaited call blocks forever.

Note: it seams that the problem occurs since I moved from a console app to a Windows Form. (the call is called from the constructor of Form1().
_client is the HttpClient dotnet class.

```
 public async Task GetConfigurationFile()
 {
       var stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(companyKey), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
       HttpResponseMessage response = null;

       // This call works and returns the respons after a few milliseconds
       response = _client.PostAsync(_configurationFileEndpoint, stringContent).Result;

       // The same awaited call block forever and never returns.
       response = await _client.PostAsync(_configurationFileEndpoint, stringContent);           
 }

  public Form1()
  {
        InitializeComponent();
        _engine = new Engine();
  }

 public Engine()
    {
        // Logic similar to this.
        Configuration configuration = null;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/configuration.json"))
            {
                configuration = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
               // Something done
        }
        _apiCall = new PlatformCommunication(configuration);

        if (configuration == null)
        {               
            try
            {
                _apiCall.GetConfigurationFile().Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: don't call `.Result`. that could result in a deadlock

Comment: @DanielA.White OP claims that `.Result` works while `await` blocks =)

Comment: I don't want to call .Result !
This is just a test. I want to call await _client.PostAsync and it suddenly blocks forever. I tested .Result and it returned the result. I want to understand why  await _client.PostAsync suddenly blocks forever. (The only change is that I moved my code from a console app to a windows form).

Comment: Windows forms do contain a Single-Threaded Apartment message pump thread, and you do have to be careful how you use it.  Are you trying to set any controls on the Winform directly from your async method?  If your async method is operating on another thread, this might be the source of your deadlock.  Try `Invoke()` instead?  Or simply wait until you've exited your async method before changing any control values.

Comment: OK, show us enough relevant code from your Winforms class (including the constructor, the class declaration and any relevant local member variables) so that we have some context for the environment your `GetConfigurationFile()` method is operating in.

Comment: In other words, we need a [mre].

Comment: From a "better practices" standpoint, I would expect `GetConfigurationFile` to return a `Task<ConfigurationFile>` object, not merely a `Task`.

Comment: I edited the question. Will try to put the code in a BackgroundWorker

Comment: @CloudAnywhere please see https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Do not do things like `_apiCall.GetConfigurationFile().Wait()`. You should not invoke async functions in ctor, it can lead to all kinds of side effects like you are experiencing here.

Comment: @YK1: to prevent blocking calls, I can move the code in the constructor of Engine() to an Async Initialize function and await _apiCall.GetConfigurationFile() instead of_apiCall.GetConfigurationFile().Wait(); But then in my Winform, I need to await engine.Initialize() from an Async function which I don't have? ( engine must run automatically, not be behind a start button), reason why I put it in the constructor of the form which is not async.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> @YK1: to prevent blocking calls, I can move the code in the
> constructor of Engine() to an Async Initialize function and await
> _apiCall.GetConfigurationFile() instead of_apiCall.GetConfigurationFile().Wait(); But then in my Winform, I
> need to await engine.Initialize() from an Async function which I don't
> have? ( engine must run automatically, not be behind a start button),
> reason why I put it in the constructor of the form which is not async.

Instead of constructor, move your startup code code to an `async` method. You can subscribe to `Form_Load` event and call that method.

```
class Engine 
{

    public async Task Init()
    {
        // Logic similar to this.
        Configuration configuration = null;
        try
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/configuration.json"))
            {
                configuration = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Configuration>(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { 
               // Something done
        }
        _apiCall = new PlatformCommunication(configuration);

        if (configuration == null)
        {               
            try
            {
                await _apiCall.GetConfigurationFile();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
private async void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _engine = new Engine();
    await _engine.Init();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are doing this:

```
_apiCall.GetConfigurationFile().Wait();
```

As explained in many places, such as [here](https://%20blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) - blocking on async code from UI thread is bad idea. When you have this:

```
response = await _client.PostAsync(_configurationFileEndpoint, stringContent);
```

the `SynchronizationContext` will be captured before await and execution after await will continue on that context, which means in this case on UI thread. It cannot continue there, because UI thread is blocked by `GetConfigurationFile().Wait()`, so you have deadlock.

When you have this:

```
response = _client.PostAsync(_configurationFileEndpoint, stringContent).Result;
```

The code inside `PostAsync` uses `ConfigureAwait(false)` on every async call, to prevent continuations running on captured context. So all continuations run on thread pool threads and you can get away with blocking on async call with Result in this case (doesn't make it good idea still). Then after this change your `GetConfigurationFile` becomes synchronous (there is no `await` left), so you can get away with `Wait()` also.

You can do the same `ConfigureAwait(false)`:

```
response = await _client.PostAsync(_configurationFileEndpoint, stringContent).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And it will help in this case, but that's not the way to solve this problem. The real way is to just not block on async code on UI thread. Move `_apiCall.GetConfigurationFile()` outside of constructor.